# create a list of the alphabet via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to produce results from the alphabet via SQL?

Something like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT 
'A','B','C'
```

But this just produces the letters across in columns.

Comment: @PrinceCheaperton Do you want to print alphabets from A to Z?

Comment: Its constant data, make a permanent [Letters] table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
--
-- tally = 9466 rows in my db, select upper & lower alphas
-- 
;
with 
cte_tally as
(
select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as n 
from sys.all_columns
)
select 
  char(n) as alpha
from 
  cte_tally
where
  (n > 64 and n < 91) or
  (n > 96 and n < 123);
go
```

The sys.all_columns is a documented table.  It will be around for a while.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177522.aspx

It seems clear that the table, sp_values,  is undocumented and can be removed in the future without any comment from Microsoft.

Answer (score 12):

Use table `spt_values` and convert values to chars

```
SELECT Char(number+65) 
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values
 WHERE name IS NULL AND 
       number < 26
```

EDIT: This table is undocumented. But, it's used by many system storedprocedures and it's extremely unlikely for this table to disappear, since all those procs should be rewritten. This would be like poking a sleeping lion.

Comment: Ooh, this is clever. Fair warning that as an undocumented feature, it may break at any point though.

Comment: @Kahn true, however you can very easily use the same logic with your own numbers table (see [here](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html), [here](http://bit.ly/1jNAMjT) and [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/)) - or using ROW_NUMBER() against any table you know to have more than 26 rows, or sys.objects, etc. I wrote about several techniques [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1), [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-2) and [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah, the cleverness part was largely because I didn't realize that you could just basically select any existing objects and use this logic to create the characters for alphabets. As you said, if nothing else, using ROW_NUMBER() to just enumerate the rows. :) Very nice!

Comment: I came to see how to make my number list into abc, so all I need is `Char(myvalue+65)`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select 'A' union
select 'B' union
select 'C'
```

Comment: And make it a table function in case you need to do it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print from A to Z, then:

```
DECLARE @i int=65
WHILE @i < 91
BEGIN
PRINT CHAR(@i);
SET @i=@i+1;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use U-SQL

```
Select
    [letter]
From
    (
        Values
            ('A')
            ,('B')
            ,('C')
    ) As [Letters]([letter])
```

Comment: (T-SQL is the same.) Great! Allows the simple, inspectable use of the symbol alphabet appropriate to the problem domain.

Answer (score 1):

```
with AlphabetList as
(
select  char(65) letter
union all
select  char(ascii(letter) + 1)
from    AlphabetList
where   letter <> 'Z'
)
select  *
from    AlphabetList
```

Comment: it would be nice if you add some explanation to the code

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive CTE (common table expression) to output the alphabet, A-Z, one row per letter/character:

```
;WITH cteAZ AS
(
SELECT ASCII('A') [AlphaCode],CAST('A' AS CHAR(1)) [Alpha]
UNION ALL
SELECT a.AlphaCode + 1 [AlphaCode],CAST(CHAR(a.AlphaCode + 1) AS CHAR(1)) [Alpha]
FROM cteAZ a WHERE a.AlphaCode < ASCII('Z')
)
SELECT 
az.AlphaCode,az.Alpha
FROM 
cteAZ az
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
;WITH CHARA2Z
AS (
    SELECT 
        [ASCII] = ASCII('A'), 
        [LETTER] = CHAR(ASCII('A'))
    
    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        [ASCII] + 1, 
        [LETTER] = CHAR([ASCII]+1)
    FROM 
        CHARA2Z
    WHERE 
        [ASCII] < ASCII('Z')
)

SELECT * FROM CHARA2Z
```

> Replace 'A' & 'Z' by 'a' & 'z' for small letters.

Answer (score 0):

Stemming from @MarkoJuvančič's answer, but a solution that will work on every SQL DBMS:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE alphabet (ltr CHAR(1));

SET @row_number = 0;

INSERT INTO alphabet
SELECT
        CHAR((@row_number:=@row_number + 1) +64) -- 'A' is the 65th character on the ASCII table
    FROM customer -- any table with 26 or more rows could suffice for this job
    WHERE @row_number < 26;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'A' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'F' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'G' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'H' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'I' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'J' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'K' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'L' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'M' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'N' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'O' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'P' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Q' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'R' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'S' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'U' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'V' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'W' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'X' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y' letter
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Z' letter;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).