# How do I insert a row into a table where one column has the next character on the ascii table for the next 11 available characters?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-insert

I am new at SQL (know enough to be dangerous but not enough to do elegant code) I am working with an existing database and they had used ascii characters as unique identifiers.For example:

```
"   Note
$   Sales Call
A   Call Back
B   Busy
C   Call Back - Appointment
D   test
E   Example Call Status
h   dafs
L   Left Message
M   New Call
```

I am trying to find a way to write a script that will add the next row to a table that has the next available ascii character.  Due to the nature of the database, I cannot change how it is set up.

I have tried Googling things like:

```
sql i need to create a row with the next character in ascii
sql add next available character
sql select next ascii character
```

Most of the results are to just see the next ascii character.

I have tried finding a way of just creating a temp table of all the ascii characters and then removing the ones that already exist, filling in the 11 rows with the information that needs to be added then stop when the next row would have a null for the description.

I found posts like [create a list of the alphabet via SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457173/create-a-list-of-the-alphabet-via-sql)

But still cannot figure out how to add to the existing or create the temp table.

```
Begin transaction

Create Table #asciitemp (
status  char,
statusdesc  varchar,
resolved    bit,
defstat bit,
notchange   bit,
backcolor   int,
forecolor   int,
timestamp   timestamp,
autocall    smallint,
statusdescF varchar,
statusdescS varchar,
handheld    bit
)

DECLARE @Counter int;  
SET @Counter = 1;  
WHILE @Counter < 256 
Set @statusascii CHAR(1) = 'A'

BEGIN   

Set @statusasciichar CHAR(1) = @statusascii CHAR(1) + 1

Insert into #asciitemp 
Value (@statusasciichar, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, timestamp, Null, Null, Null, Null)

END  

Deleted from #asciitemp 
where #asciitemp.status = #CallStatus.status
```

--I know that this is EXTREMELY novice and messy but I am trying to piece it together with chunks of code from various sources on the internet.

Ideally I would like to be able to add the rows directly to the table but am willing to add the information to a temp table and then copy it to the actual table. Outside of brute forcing it by creating a table will all the ascii values and deleting the ones that already exist, I am at a loss.

Comment: so have you tried to run your current stored procedure and it doesn't work? I don't fully understand what your goal is

Comment: Do you simply want to calculate the next primary key (ascii character) when you insert a row or specifically pre-fill the next 11 rows?  Are non-printable ASCII characters allowed?

Comment: What database software are you using, e.g. SQL Server? What version? (`select @@Version` in SQL Server.)

Comment: Ok so now I have a better handle on what questions people need information for I hope I can fill in some of the gaps.

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 16299: )

Comment: Ok so now I have a better handle on what questions people need information for I hope I can fill in some of the gaps.

Version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 16299: )

There is no stored procedure, currently when you click the new button to create a new entry in the run time, it will add the next available ascii character. Once you click save, it inserts what you added to the screen into the database table.

Comment: Originally the Runtime was written in FoxPro and then it was modified to use SQL for the database. Parts started to be made in .NET but that was abandoned to move it to more of an online html5 interface.

So in a nutshell, there are multiple servers each independent of each other that all use the same data structure.

Some are local installs that have a server on site and use a runtime that was originally written in foxpro but was converted to work with some .NET components.

Comment: Some local installs have been moved to a cloud server that hosts the SQL database and those can be accessed with an HTML5 website but still need to be accessed by the runtime.

Since the data is now easier to access, some things like needing to access the server through a Bomgar support session is no longer needed.

Currently, each row of information has to be entered through the runtime or website that links to the SQL database.

I am trying to find a way to automate the task because if I can get the script figured out, the developers might be able to add it as a button to add the info.

Comment: So what I need is to be able to have the script look at the currently used ascii characters and select the next one in sequence that is not being used. 

For Example, if the currently used characters are:

    A   Call Back
    B   Busy
    C   Call Back - Appointment
    D   test

The script would insert E Left Message.

If E is already used, it would be F Left Message.

I do not have access to the source code to see how the program is determining the next letter and when I clicked the Add button, the Profiler did not show anything sent the the server. Only Save touched the data.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, this is all new to me and I have been self teaching SQL. This is the first thing that has truly stumped me.

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this work for you? May not be a complete answer but it's a start (and I can update this post accordingly.)

```
WITH 
E1(N)     AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS x(x)),
iTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM E1, E1 a, E1 b)
Insert into #asciitemp 
SELECT TOP (255) 
CHAR(i.N), Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, NULL, Null, Null, Null, Null
--i.N, C = CHAR(i.N)
FROM iTally AS i;
```

Another way (using a temp table for a demo you can copy/paste run)...

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (N INT IDENTITY, somecol BIT, C AS CHAR(N));

INSERT @table (somecol)
SELECT TOP (255) 1
FROM sys.all_columns;

-- compare results
SELECT t.* FROM @table AS t;
```

Comment: That second one looks like it might work for what I am trying to do. I will let you know as soon as I can.

Comment: I think I got what I needed with the following:

Created Table and ran first script then:


    Delete TOP(37) from #asciitemp

    Delete FROM #asciitemp
    where status In (Select status from actstat)